# How to prevent Flask (python) from emitting html?

Tags: python, flask

It appears that Flask assumes that the server is returning html to the client (browser).

Here's a simple example;

```
import json
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
  msg = ['Hello, world!']
  return json.dumps(msg) + '\n'
```

This code works as expected and returns the desired json;

```
$ curl -s http://localhost:5000/
["Hello, world!"]
```

But if I introduce an error;

```
import json
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
  msg = ['Hello, world!']
  return json.dumps(XXmsg) + '\n'
```

Then Flask emits the error wrapped in several pages worth of html, starting like;

```
$ curl -s http://localhost:5000/
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>NameError: name 'XXmsg' is not defined
 // Werkzeug Debugger</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="?__debugger__=yes&amp;cmd=resource&amp;f=style.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon"
        href="?__debugger__=yes&amp;cmd=resource&amp;f=console.png">
    <script src="?__debugger__=yes&amp;cmd=resource&amp;f=debugger.js"></script>
    <script>
      var CONSOLE_MODE = false,
          EVALEX = true,
          EVALEX_TRUSTED = false,
          SECRET = "Mq5TSy6QE4OuOHUfvk8b";
    </script>
  </head>
  <body style="background-color: #fff">
    <div class="debugger">
```

Emitting html makes sense if you're creating a page load app. But I'm creating an api that only returns json.

Is there anyway to prevent Flask from emitting html at all?

Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the section [Returning API Errors as JSON](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/errorhandling/#returning-api-errors-as-json) of the Flask docs.

Basically, you have to replace the default error handler with a function that returns the error as json. A very basic example:

```py
@app.errorhandler(HTTPException)
def handle_exception(exception):
    response = exception.get_response()
    response.content_type = "application/json"
    response.data = json.dumps({"code": exception.code})
    return response
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted response gives a good hint for handling `HTTPException` but it won't work for all exceptions unless you create a handler for the mother of all exceptions:`Exception`. And you might not want to do this for security reasons, if you have some custom defined exceptions with sensible data it'll get handled by this handler.

I suspect the true reason you have those lengthy html responses is because you started your flask app with the `--debug` option.

Comment: What's annoying to me is the fact that my api has html embedded in it at all. A restful api that returns json should not have html embedded in it. This tells me that Flask was invented to spew out html and there's no direct way to remove it or disable it. Tells me that flask isn't directly suitable for a restful api. Any comments to that anyone?

Comment: Sorry I've not been very explicit in my answer: The HTML you shared is the Flask debugger's HTML, it contains a python  traceback. It is useful when debugging an API deployed in a preprod environment. You can turn it off by not executing with the --debug option